# Ignore unreachable statement error (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android

How to ignore unreachable statement in Java/Android studio purposely.

This is just for testing, for example, I have a lot of codes below it, and I just want to do `return` above the codes for testing purpose.

Currently it gives error in Android Studio and I can't run it.

An alternative would be to comment the codes below, but I do this a lot, and it's a little cumbersome.

Thanks.

Comment: You can comment/uncomment multiple lines in Android studio at once, why not do that?

Comment: @Kevin, I wrote that in my question above. I do this a lot, just for testing some parts, and it's a little time wasting to comment and uncomment lines. In XCode, it just simply gives you a warning.

Comment: I do this sometimes as well but writing return vs highlighting the rest of the lines in a method and pressing Ctrl + / is about the same for me

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate question, but the answer there don't satisfy me. But I found the real answer in one of the comments there, which is : `if (true) return;`